# Using vb6 dll. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. It works on development but fails on deployment asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm using a vb6 dll, running on development works perfectly, when deployed (published in the same development machine) throws this error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Like i said, it is the same machine, so i dont know what can be wrong.
I already set defaultapppool to enable 32 bits apps, the platform in debug configuration is x86 also.

I tried to copy the dll file to the bin folder of the project published folder, and nothing happened.

The error does get fired when the function CalcularNecesidadPedido is called.

```
Dim calc As New WinBlindCalculoProd.WBCalculoProd
        Try

            If calc.CalcularNecesidadPedido(cnnpedidos, Distribuidor.SelectedItem.Value.ToString, argument(0)) Then
```

It doesnt even trigger the catch, just throw the error message from above.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to be on this insert of the vb6 dll:

```
strSQL = "Insert Into NecessidadePedido (Cliente,PedidoVenda,ItemVenda,Sequencia,DataExplosion," & _
                " Uso,TipoComponente,Setor,Almoxarifado,TipoDocumento, " & _
                " Componente,CorComponente,Manter_Estoque,Dimensoes,CompraEspecifica,TipoEstoque," & _
                " Altura,Largura,Comprimento,OrdemMontagem,QtdNecessaria,Consumo) Values('" & Cliente & "','" & Pedido & "'," & intItem & "," & intSequencia & _
                "," & PrepDate(Now(), CNN, True) & _
                ",'" & strUso & "','" & strTipoComponente & "','" & strSetor & "','" & strAlmoxarifado & "','" & strTipoDocumento & "','" & _
                strComponente & "','" & strCor & "'," & Cbit(blnManter_Estoque) & "," & intDimensoes & "," & Cbit(blnCompraEspecifica) & ",'" & sTipoEstoque & _
                "'," & sngAltura & "," & sngLargura & "," & sngComprimento & "," & Cbit(blnOrdemMontagem) & "," & sngQuantidade & "," & sngConsumo & ")"

                CNN.Execute strSQL
```

I extract the strSQL string from development and deployment, this how they look like:

Dev: `Insert Into NecessidadePedido (Cliente,PedidoVenda,ItemVenda,Sequencia,DataExplosion, Uso,TipoComponente,Setor,Almoxarifado,TipoDocumento,  Componente,CorComponente,Manter_Estoque,Dimensoes,CompraEspecifica,TipoEstoque, Altura,Largura,Comprimento,OrdemMontagem,QtdNecessaria,Consumo) 
Values('1','16784',1,11,{ts '2019-03-21 15:44:14'},'000','99','0001','01','PV','010216','000',1,1,0,'0',0,0,1250,1,1,1.25)`

Dep: `Insert Into NecessidadePedido (Cliente,PedidoVenda,ItemVenda,Sequencia,DataExplosion, Uso,TipoComponente,Setor,Almoxarifado,TipoDocumento,  Componente,CorComponente,Manter_Estoque,Dimensoes,CompraEspecifica,TipoEstoque, Altura,Largura,Comprimento,OrdemMontagem,QtdNecessaria,Consumo) 
Values('1','16784',1,11,{ts '2019-03-21 15:41:27'},'000','99','0001','01','PV','010216','000',1,1,0,'0',0,0,1250,1,1,1,25)`

So the problem seems to be that **consumo** value, on deplyoment throws comma instead of dot for decimals. When i comment that line, it works on deployment.

I already tried to change the region settings of this pc, it didn't work.
Any ideas? I don't want to modify that dll because it is used on other projects.

Comment: That answer has little to do with calling unmanaged vb6 dll's. Of course the poster gets a null object, because the unmanaged vb6 dll call is not working, not because some object not initialized. If you take that assuming, then we would NEVER have to answer a question on SO. I mean, I flip the switch and the light don't go on. You can't just post to a answer that says the light bulb not getting electricity as a valid answer. We have to suggest a broken wire, a tripped fuse, light bulb not screwed in all the way. Telling everyone the bulb is not getting electric (or null object) is not a answer

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on that line.  Does it reach the breakpoint?

Comment: If a put a breakpoint on that line, it means that i'm running it on development on visual studio, it works perfectly on development, the problem happens when project is deployed.

Comment: I suspect a dependency of the VB6 DLL is missing.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but why works on development? i'm using the same machine.

Comment: Filepaths? Debug versus release?

Comment: Nope, the object creates without problem. I think i'll have to find the source code of that vb6 dll.

Comment: You want to set the Application Locale, or the Users Locale, not the PC region.

Comment: Are you running your dev environment under administrator privileges? That VB6 code and modules assume unfettered access to now-sensitive folders and Registry settings can be the source of difficult-to-trace runtime bugs.

Comment: Since i added the reference to that dll, i have to open visual studio as administrator, otherwise i get this error `Cannot register assembly 'absolute\path\to\NameOf.dll' access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator.`

Comment: Given that, I suspect your problem is that the VB6 DLL lacks the privileges for certain operations it must perform. I have come across this issue in the recent past myself.

Comment: Is there a way to reopen this question? I would like to share the workaround i did, i have to edit the dll on that string. However the duplicate link didnt help at all. Thanks to everyone that helped.

Comment: It's easier to create a new question, and answer it yourself.